# Porting data with MongoDB+Node: how to keep ObjectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-modules

I'm porting data from the prod db to dev of many and large collections with a NodeJs + mongodb (^5.5.0) lambda: looking up online I went for [this Mongodb approach](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/export-and-import-data-from-collection-in-mongodb-using-nodejs/8321/2). I successfully write/read/delete the tmp file where I store my prod data and write them in the dev environment.

The huge problem is that all ObjectIds field are ported as String type: this makes sense, since I store the data as JSON in a tmp file.
This is an example of my porting result:

```
{
    "_id" : "615b139a436609145e5cc86d",
    "name" : "This object is now in DEV",
    "other_collection_ref_id_now_is_String" : "615b1399436609145e5cc859"
}
```

Is there a way to tell MongoDB or to my Node / Mongodb driver to detect (?) and recast these fields to ObjectIds? Maybe declaring and setting, somewhere in mongo's operations, the schema validation?
I really believe it's some config or something similar I'm missing, if anyone could give me a piece of advice it would be really apprecciated.

I know I could use a cursor or something similar, but since the amount of data is a lot I'd really love to avoid loops and do something smoother.

Comment: Feels to me like you're re-inventing the wheel here a little bit. The `mongodump` and `mongorestore` utilities (along with `mongoexport` and `mongoimport`) are already designed to efficiently move data. If you do want to do things yourself, perhaps take advantage of extended JSON, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId)

Comment: I need to do some logic while exporting/importing, which is why I would avoid mongodump and mongorestore (maybe I'm wrong?). Very nice tip about EJSON, but do I need to declare every collection schema/json I want to import, correct? Thank you so!